# How to Dynamically Manage Docker Containers in Kubernetes with a Python Script?

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes

I have a Python script `runContainers.py` that currently uses subprocess to dynamically create and manage Docker containers based on a `clientList.json` file. The script chunks the client list and creates a Docker container for each chunk. Now, I'm transitioning to Kubernetes and need to adapt my script to update a ConfigMap and manage container orchestration accordingly.

The script does the following:

1. Updates `clientList.json` with new client data.
2. Creates a ConfigMap from `clientList.json`.
3. Dynamically creates Docker containers using the chunks from `clientList.json`.

I am very new to Docker and Kubernetes.

I am looking for a way to transition this app to Kubernetes.

Here's my script for context:

```
import json
import subprocess
import os
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from src import clientListUpdate

clientListUpdate.updateClientJson()
chunkSize = 3

def clientChunks(clientList, chunkSize):
    chunks = []
    for i in range(0, len(clientList), chunkSize):
        chunks.append(clientList[i:i + chunkSize])
    return chunks


with open('./data/clientList.json', 'r') as file:
    clients = json.load(file)

dockerImageName = 'client_upload_image'

processes = []

for chunk in clientChunks(clients, chunkSize):
    with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False) as tempFile:
        json.dump(chunk, tempFile)
        tempFile_path = tempFile.name
    
    process = subprocess.Popen([
        'docker', 'run', '--rm',
        '-v', f"{tempFile_path}:/app/client_data.json",
        dockerImageName, 
        'python', '/app/clientUpload.py'  
    ])
    processes.append((process, tempFile_path))

# Wait for all containers to finish and clean up temporary files
for process, tempFile_path in processes:
    process.wait()
    os.remove(tempFile_path)
```

Comment: You probably would use the Kubernetes API to spawn a new Pod (or maybe a [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/)) for each container.

Comment: Also remember that Kubernetes can't access your local system, and ConfigMaps have a ~1 MiB limit.  If the data is somewhat large, you'll need to figure out how to get it into the cluster.

Comment: For generic "I have a bunch of data and I want containers to process them" issues like this, have you looked into using a message-queueing system like RabbitMQ, or maybe a Python-native task system like Celery?  A producer like what you show here would write messages into the job queue.  You would then separately run some number of workers to process the tasks.  This isn't specific to any container system, and you could run it totally locally without containers, or run the same code unmodified in Kubernetes.